# boost::lock_guard allocation, constructor, and destructor overhead

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, locking, mutex

I'm learning about mutexes and I see that, to use a lock guard, every iteration you have to allocate memory for the lock guard, call the constructor, and then call the destructor. It seems like this could be a significant amount of overhead compared to a lock that never goes out of scope. I understand the advantage of a lock guard, but how much time could I save by avoiding them? Or, to put it another way, how small does the thread's work per iteration have to be to make the lock guard overhead significant?

```
prepare_data();
{
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mut);
    data_ready=true;
}
cond.notify_one();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No allocation is needed. The compiler can see precisely what the constructor and destructor do and optimize out the need for any allocation of memory or initialization of an object or any need to call a specific constructor or destructor function.

It can see that the constructor does nothing but call the lock function of the mutex and that the destructor does nothing but call the unlock function. The address of the `lock_guard` is never taken, so there is no need for one.

This is one of the key reasons RAII is recommended in C++ -- it usually has no cost whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will most likely have to allocate space on the stack to store a reference to the mutex for the `lock_guard` destructor. It will unlikely cache it because (a) locking/unlocking the mutex are external function calls and (b) the functions impose memory fences. But the cost of locking/unlocking the mutex is so much greater than the other operations associated with the `lock_guard` that there is no practical reason to avoid it. Besides, modern compilers have very efficient techniques with regard to stack management, and allocating the space for the reference may actually be a no-op.